# After running build on my quasar vuejs app: >app:build Built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server

Tags: vue.js, quasar

How can i run the index file? How can I serve it on github.

> app:build Opening index.html over file:// won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can host your app on firebase hosting.
Go to https://console.firebase.google.com , and create a project.
Download the firebase-tools and deploy your built files there.
Additionally, you can also use the cloud messaging from firestore in your app.
For localhost, you can use "serve" module.

Comment: Wow thanks. Serve module ran the app in my localhost. How about github? is it not possible to host it there?